# oracle select insite ksh failing with colsep

Tags: oracle, ksh

I am running the following code inside a ksh script, and it doesn't apply the formatting, even if I try to add it manually.

```
ato_detail=`sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
connect xxx/xxxxx@xxxx
set feedback off
set pages 0
set termout off
set trimspool on
set colsep ','
spool tmp.log
spool ato_detail.log
select name,date, hism_logic_id from main_db.omp where type = 'ZW' and date >= sysdate-(48/24);
EOF`
```

When I receive the output, or the output at the file it doesn't have the format I added, it just shows the rows.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you get, and what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the SQL Part in a `.sql` file

`test.sql`

```
set feedback off
set pages 0
set termout off
set trimspool on
set colsep ','
spool tmp.log
spool ato_detail.log
select name,date, hism_logic_id from main_db.omp where type = 'ZW' and date >= sysdate-(48/24);
```

and then you may try-

```
#!/bin/ksh

sqlplus -s xxx/xxxxx@xxxx /nolog <<EOF
@test.sql
exit
EOF
```

See if this solves the problem.